# Facebook Like button not displaying

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to add a Facebook *Like* button to a site but it never shows up.

Here's the relevant detail from my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" 
    xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="[____].com" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.[____].com/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://[____].gif" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="[____].com" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[____]" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/css/[____].min.css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                    appId: '[____]',
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true
                });
                FB.XFBML.parse(); **- 1**
        };
        FB.XFBML.parse(); **- 2**
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());
    </script>

    Like button goes here:<fb:like></fb:like>

    ...

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is quite simply that while the script does load, the *Like* button never appears. I've also run it through the Facebook Linter which doesn't highlight any problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. I eventually realised that one of my Firefox add-ons, Ghostery, was blocking the Like button.

So the code I originally posted does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to [`FB.XHTML.parse();`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after the FB object is initialized.

Comment: I've just tried this - I've edited my original post to show **-1** and **-2**, the two locations where I've tried your suggestion.
In both locations it makes no difference.
The code I had in my original post (which is simply excluding the FB.XFBML.parse()) is exactly as Facebook offer on their example page right after I registered my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a synchronous reference to see if it works?

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```